# How to write the flow control in the multi-line string for Helm Chart template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

---

When we use the Helm, yaml is the language to write the chart.

Any suggestion to have the flow control in the multi-line string?

For example, how to write the correct for this yaml file?

```
coffee: |
  {{- if eq .Values.favorite.drink "coffee" }}
  Latte
  Cappuccino
  {{- end }}
  Espresso
```

Comment: That seems like it should be correct; there's no rule that the `if` and `end` have to be on the same line.  You do need to take some care with the `-` white-space control but I think what you show here is right.  What result do you actually get?  (Try `helm template --debug` if it's a YAML parse error.)

Answer (score 0):

The first control structure we'll look at is for conditionally including blocks of text in a template. This is the if/else block.

```yaml
{{ if PIPELINE }}
  # Do something
{{ else if OTHER PIPELINE }}
  # Do something else
{{ else }}
  # Default case
{{ end }}
```

So, you can use the following

```yaml
- name: Name_here
{{- if .Values.somecondition }}
  value: "firstValue"
{{- else }}
  value: "secondValue"
{{- end }}
```

Refer to [official docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/) for more details